# Cannot submit App to iTunes using Version XCode 7.3.1 and OS X 10.11.6

Tags: ios, xcode

I get this error;

New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, macOS, and iOS SDK. Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta macOS builds.

Now I cannot upgrade OS X as my laptop is too old, and I could install XCode but I don't have enough HDD space.

The version of XCode I have is from the App Store...

Any ideas?

Comment: Try doing a clean build. There may be something left over from when you were using a beta version of Xcode in the past.

Comment: Did you just apply Security Update 2016-002 for El Capitan? I'm in the same case, with XCode 8 (8A218a), with an app that was "submittable" until yesterday. I never used any beta version of xcode in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do believe that the issue is the combination and timing of the XCode and OS X version.

I could only resolve the issue by updating to the latest XCode and then reachiving and submitting the App, it then passed verification.

Whether Apple post a solution to support the older OS and XCode combination is beyond my control, but I can confirm the XCode update solved this, and my new build is pending review.

Comment: I agree with the timing. I was already using the last Xcode version, but the 2016-002 El Capitan Security Update updated the OS version which is included in the archive .plist. Apple seems to take a while to allow new OS versions in iTunes Connect. I did not change anything and it finally work.